# Return a status 404 and an error message in response to an AJAX request, in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to get x-editable working (to allow inline form edits), using Rails 3.2

When I receive the post from the browser via AJAX, I need to be able to validate the form input and send back a response.

If its successful, I just need:

```
render :nothing => true
```

and this works ok.

If unsuccessful, according to their documentation I need to send back the equivalent of this PHP snippet:

```
header('HTTP 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
echo "This field is required!";
```

I cannot figure out how to do this in Rails.

If I try a simple render :status => 400, then my terminal output looks as follows:

Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

And I can find no information on how to combine a 400 error with an actual message

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
render text: "This field is required!", status: :bad_request
```

Comment: This seems to work (though actually with x-editable if you leave the :status message out it still flags the text as an error)

Answer (score 3):

What you're after is:

```
head :no_content, :status => :bad_request
```

This makes it explicit that you’re only generating HTTP headers

Comment: That seems to return a whole html file which in this case (ie using x-editable) appears in the return window

Comment: really? This is coming directly from Rails official documentation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses

Comment: ok, I'm being a bit dumb here (now realise u can use Chrome debug to view ajax request-response, lol). So ajax posts to a controller that has a single line in it, being head :no_content etc. This throws a no method error (NoMethodError (undefined method `head' for etc) and thus returns status 500 and the Rails error message (which was the html I mentioned in my comment above). I'm working within an Apotomo widget, which may be why head doesnt work. Not sure, need to set up a better test

Comment: I think you're right. I am not familiar with apotomo but a quick look at its rdoc indicates that head is not supported.

Comment: OK, that explains it. I'll look at it outside Apotomo for my own enlightenment. Cheers

Comment: Also, where would response content go along with the bad_request, as that's part of my original question? Also, I need to test Michael Lawrie's suggestion outside of Apotomo also

Answer (score 2):

That PHP example doesn't include "This field is required!" in the response, instead it's printed out.

You'll want to respond with just an HTTP header with status code `400 Bad Request`, as seen in:

```
header('HTTP 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
```

In Rails you can use this:

```
head :bad_request
# or
head 400
```

Or this, but it's less explicit to the reader that you're generating just the header:

```
render nothing: true, status: :bad_request
# or
render nothing: true, status: 400
```

If you *do* want to include a body with text in the response (so not just a header):

```
render text: "This field is required!", status: :bad_request
# or
render text: "This field is required!", status: 400
```